# MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

I'm working on a project with an other guy and I just pulled the new version of the code he released on github.
We are using Magical Record, and now I have this error when I launch the app ( build succeeded ) :

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to class...
```

But when I look at my AppDelegate, I've got :

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"DBModel"];
```

DBModel is the name of my data model ( DBModel.xcdatamodeld ).

I made some researches on the Internet, but I didn't find anything.

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot !

**SOLUTION FOUND**

I just checked all of my compile sources, MagicalRecord+Setup.m was missing..

Comment: That's why you should use CocoaPods instead of manual inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Did you link CoreData.framework to project?
And you should create url for your sqlite file and after that add to this method

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. CoreData.framework is linked to the project. I'll try to create url for my data model.

Comment: I can't find how to create url for data model :/.
Is this possible that this error occurs because  MR_SHORTHAND is not defined ? When I define it, the system tells me "No known class method for selector SwizzleShorthandsMethod" anyway.

Comment: for example:  
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kNameOfDataBaseSQLite ofType:@"sqlite"]];

Comment: and use this: + (void) setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreAtURL:(NSURL *)storeURL;

Comment: Thanks a lot spbvasilenko. When I replace "kNameOfDataBaseSQLite" with the name of my data model, the system says that my url is nil, which means that my data model isn't in the main bundle ?
Sorry for these probably stupid questions, I just don't get how all of these things work..

Comment: You should use name of your sqlite file, not data model

Comment: I don't have any sqlite file actually, or I don't find it. Is it automatically created with Magical Records ?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually use the following import, it will then import the rest of the Magical Record headers for you to avoid importing each separately.

```
#import <MagicalRecord/CoreData+MagicalRecord.h>
```

Or

```
#import "CoreData+MagicalRecord.h"
```

Depending on how you have Magical Record in your project.